# i could not send mail to yahoo user by using nodemailer in node.js

Tags: node.js, yahoo, nodemailer

I am trying to send confirmation mail to GMail and Yahoo users in node.js by using nodemailer.  I tried this:

```
nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",
        {
                 service: 'gmail',
                 auth:
                 {
                        user: "xxx@gmail.com",
                        pass: "xxxx"
                 }
        });
 var message ={

                        from: 'XXX.com',
                        to:xxx@gmail.com,
                        subject: 'Confirm your registration',

              }
```

It is working fine for Gmail but i want to send Yahoo so i have given `yahoo` instead of `service:Gmail` but shows the following error:

> Mail from command failed - 553 From address not verified - see
>   http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

How do I send mail to Yahoo?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the `service` for a different destination. I.e. if you're supplying gmail log-in credentials and sending an email to yahoo, your service is still 'gmail'.